# Programmatically resolving conflicts with Bootstrap and in-house CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a question that isn't quite answered by other questions I've found.

We have an in-house CSS framework, but also use bootstrap for a fair number of projects.  I've run into some issues that aren't handled by cascading.  For example, our in-house framework has a styling for a tags.  We do not have any stylings for a:hover, a:focus, etc; however, bootstrap does, which changes how our links look, but isn't solved by cascading.

I am not in control of the framework so I can't build it in.  Currently, I am using a style sheet that has a:hover, a:focus, etc that effectively set those styles back to what our in-house a tag looks like.  I can't use inherit or initial or anything like that since we have a specific styling.

Is there a better way to do this without changing our actual framework or cutting things out of bootstrap?

I can't share more than 2 links yet, so look at the plunks on my profile:

```
Plunker:
```

http://plnkr.co/users/ZDTaylor

Comment: Have you tried using the Bootstrap css and then adding your own? Do it like this <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom CSS: You can use this stylesheet to override any Bootstrap styles and/or apply your own styles -->
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: That what I currently have.  First bootstrap, then the in-house framework, then my manual fixes.  The problem is the in-house framework doesn't have some tags (ie. a:hover), so it can't overwrite bootstrap.  That's why I have a third css file with a:hover to override that.  But I would like a way to either eliminate the need for the 3rd css file or programmatically create the 3rd css file with the conflict resolution, as I'm sure I will find other conflicts.

Comment: edit your question and post all of your code then and a link if the site is live to look at

Comment: it has been edited